# Formatting time-duration into dd:hh:mm format using moment.js - error

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Im trying to count a duration in **DD-HH-mm format**.

My javascript looks like this:

```
var seconds=180;
```

```
var duration=moment.utc(seconds*1000).format('DD:HH:mm');
```

It should return something like this: **00:00:03**
But moment.js just return this: **01:00:03**

Why??

Thanks in advance! jonas

Comment: `DD` is day of month. I think you are trying to do `HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: Id like to get `days-hours-minutes (dd-hh-mm)` as result (as local time duration!) @SaugatAcharya

Comment: As far as I get it, the output is right. It is saying it's day 1.

Comment: Ok, sure but the result should be a duration result `(1 day = 24hours | 1 hours = 60minutes | 1 minute = 60seconds)` @SaugatAcharya

Comment: I don't get you. Try using `HH:mm:ss` if you want it in hours. As I've already mentioned, `DD` is day of month. So there is practically no day 0 in any month.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [*Formatting seconds duration into DD:HH:mm format by using moment.js*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112569/formatting-seconds-duration-into-ddhhmm-format-by-using-moment-js). You can't use date formatting tokens for durations, since the date is not zero based and has a limit of 31 days (assuming the base date is 1 Jan).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to multiple seconds with 1000 to get desired output. Generally, only milliseconds need to multiplied by 1000.

Below code will give you desired output as : **00:00:03**

```
var seconds=180;
var duration=moment.utc(seconds).format('DD:HH:mm');
```