# Formatting seconds duration into DD:HH:mm format by using moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to count calculate a duration from seconds into a **DD-HH-mm format.**

My javascript code:

```
var seconds = 120;
var result = moment.utc(seconds*1000).format('DD:HH:mm');
```

My code should return something like this: **00:00:02** *(DD:HH:MM)* but it returns that: **01:00:02** *(DD:HH:MM)*!

I'm sure that's because of my local time, but how to fix the 1 hour interval in general?

Comment: `DD:HH:mm` does not have seconds component! Do you want something like `Hour:Minute:Seconds` instead?

Comment: Sure `DD:HH:mm` does not have seconds component... I'd like to convert a specific count of seconds (120) to my  `DD:HH:mm` format bro @NisargShah

Answer (score 0):

`moment.utc` creates a moment.js object with a timezone set to GMT/UTC. When using a date for a duration, you need to allow for the date starting from 1, not zero. Also, if the duration is 32 days or longer, the "days" will reset to 1.

Moment.js also has [durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/), however, they don't support formatting other than "[humanize](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/)" or converting to particular units.

If your durations are less than 32 days, you can use a date starting from 1 January in any year provided you deal with the day number not being zero indexed (i.e. subtract 1 from the day).

So getting your required format with moment.js is a bit more work than just formatting a date, you'll need a sequence of steps so consider writing a function. A plain JS function is no more work than a moment one in this case, it will handle durations 32 days or longer and is not affected by Date vagaries like daylight saving and timezones.

```js
var secs = 120;

// Using a duration
var m = moment.duration(secs * 1000);
console.log(m);
console.log(m.humanize());
console.log(m.asMinutes());

// Using a date and seconds value
var x = moment.utc(secs*1000);
// Generated date
console.log(x.format());
// Get the days separately
var dayNum = x.format('D') - 1;
// Format with hours and minutes
console.log(('0'+dayNum).slice(-2) + x.format(':HH:mm'))

// Function using moment.js
function myFormat(secs) {
  var x = moment.utc(secs*1000);
  var dayNum = x.format('D') - 1;
  return ('0'+dayNum).slice(-2) + x.format(':HH:mm');
}

// Function without using a Date
function duration(secs) {
  function z(n){return ('0'+n).slice(-2)}
  return z((secs/8.64e4|0)) 
         + ':' + z((secs%8.64e4)/3.6e3|0)
         + ':' + z((secs%3.6e3)/60|0)
//         + ':' + z(secs%60);
}

console.log(duration(secs));

// Some other tests
var min = 60;
var hr  = 60*min; // 3,600
var day = 24*hr;  // 86,400

//2 days 17 hours 53 minutes and 08 seconds
var d = 2*day + 17*hr + 53*min + 8;
//0 days 1 hour 2 minutes and 1 second 
var e = 0*day + 1*hr + 2*min + 1;
// 48 days 21 hours 15 minutes
var f = 48*day + 21*hr + 15*min;
 
[120, d, e, f].forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(d + ' seconds');
  console.log('Plain js:  ' + duration(d));
  console.log('Moment fn: ' + myFormat(d));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The format seems ambiguous, I think many would interpret it as HH:mm:ss rather than DD:HH:mm.